# Can I ask for book suggestions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, asking-questions

For example, can I ask for **book suggestions** regarding a particular **design style**?

Comment: We have a [resource-recommendation tag](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) for questions like these :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the on-topic help page it says:

> Graphic Design SE is for questions targeted toward design
>   professionals, students, and enthusiasts. This includes questions
>   about:
>
> - graphic arts theory and history;

So my guess would be **yes** you can. Maybe though you could broaden the question to include a short definition of an art style, some examples and book suggestions? I think this could definitely result in interesting and relevant Q&A's.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes though I would be a bit more specific about your intended use of the book (i.e. are you looking for examples of a style or looking for tutorials regarding a specific style).

It might also be a good idea to include a "What have you found?" so far, akin to "What have you tried?".

I've asked a [question regarding book suggestions of graphic design education that had a good reception here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95549/what-are-your-key-books-for-reflecting-about-graphic-design-education), if that can be helpful.